# neo4j: LOAD CSV doubled first data record of the CSV

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a bug somewhere in my query - and any help would be very appreciated. I use LOAD CSV to import data into my DB. The CSV for testing is

```
"User1","Group1"
"User2","Group2"
"User3","Group3"
"User1","Group1"
"User2","Group2"
```

Result for the import should be

- Every user is imported as a node without double entry
- Every group is imported without double entries
- The relationship between user and group is implemented

I work with this query:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:....." AS csvLine
MERGE (u:User { name: csvLine[0]})
MERGE (g:Group { name: csvLine[1]}) 
CREATE (u)-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(g)
```

Whenever I run the import I get all as expected with one exception. The first user in the csv file is always doubled - I have always two nodes with the first user name. All other users exists exactly one time. I would be happy to learn what's wrong with this approach - any comments are appreciated.

Thanks
Balael

Comment: Please note, that this query will eagerly pull in all data, I'd separate node creation from creating the relationships. Also make sure to have the unique constraints for `:User(name)` and `:Group(name)` in place to make this fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and ended up with 3 Users, 3 Groups and the relationships connecting them exactly as you'd expect:

```
load csv from "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mneedham/256b809f5622aebc311f/raw/0be2d9fac59ee453314c140f778c25b8fcad4b4c/file.csv" as csvLine
MERGE (u:User { name: csvLine[0]})
MERGE (g:Group { name: csvLine[1]}) 
CREATE (u)-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(g)
```

Can you show the output of doing:

```
MATCH (u:User) RETURN u
```

and:

```
MATCH (g:Group) RETURN g
```

Thanks
Mark

Comment: 1st: query: name User1
name User2
name User3
name User1

Comment: 2nd query: name Group1
name Group2
name Group3

Comment: Trying your CSV file generates the correct result. Thats strange. Is there maybe a difference between the protocol file / http?

Comment: I just made a new plain text file just to be sure with "1","A"
"2","B"
"3","C"
"1","B"
"3","B" and the user 1 is again 2 times there with a relation towards A and B whereas user 3 is correctly only 1 time there and connected to B and C.

Comment: Probably broken csv file? Try csvkit, perhaps windows newlines, or BOM, or binary zeros in there?

Comment: Hi all, thank sfor your suppport. I have remade all csv-files and now it works as expected. I couldnt figure out what was wrong with the csv original csv-file though I converted it in any form I coudl think of - but anyway. Seems it was really the file - so case closed. Thanks again for your time.